# Why are checkboxes missing in this R shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

When I run this R Shiny App in the default R studio R Shiny App viewer, there are no checkboxes displayed and I can't figure out why.
library(shiny)

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Fake App"),

   # Input
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput('disp', 'Display:', c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                           selected = c(1))
      ),
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Draw plot
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
     ggplot()+ geom_point(aes(x=input$disp, y=input$disp)) 
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Script Output:

```
> runApp('test')

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6460
```

This is how the app looks when I run it:
[image: RShiny App Appearance]

Could it be the port I am running this on? The network I'm connected to? (No, right? This is running locally?) Thanks so much for the insight on this!

Additional version information:

```
> R.version
           _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
year           2017                        
month          11                          
day            30                          
svn rev        73796                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree     
> packageVersion("shiny")
[1] ‘1.1.0’
```

Comment: Hi, your app works properly. Beside ggplot2 it is not loaded, and you should, there is no bug or error. In fact I executed it without problem. Maybe you need to reinstall shiny ?

Comment: I can confirm, there are no erros and checkboxes are shown correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Some additional poking around revealed that viewing the app in browser displayed the checkboxes, so figured the issue must be in RStudio. Rebooting my computer fixed my issue so the checkboxes are now shown in the RStudio shiny app viewer.

...Have you tried turning it on & off again? XD

Thanks for your help all who commented!

Comment: I have just confirmed it, in fact just opening in the browser made it.